# VisualStateManager on ListBox

Tags: c#, templates, binding, visualstatemanager

I'm trying to use the VisualStateManager on a ListBox. The code below WORKS on Windows Phone, but not on Windows Store apps. When I selected a ListBoxItem, the selecteditem in the ViewModel has a value, but the VisualStateManager doesn't work. Even when I click on a ListBoxItem, the UI is still the same (means it doesn't look like it would be selected).

This is the code:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedListBox, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         x:Name="lbuser" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Gray" 
         Height="390" Width="480" Background="Gray" IsTabStop="True" SelectionMode="Single">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate/>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Grid >
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".2"/>
        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".4" />
        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
        <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5"/>
        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" />
            <ContentPresenter
                  x:Name="contentPresenter"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Height="110">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="42"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="94"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="152"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="Bezeichnung" Text="{Binding Path=Bezeichnung}" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Stkl"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=MySelectedStkl.Stkl}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Text="Bruttolohn"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Path=Bruttolohn, Converter={StaticResource EuroConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="Alter"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=Alter}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Text="Nettolohn"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Path=Nettolohn, Converter={StaticResource EuroConverter}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Jahr"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Path=MySelectedLoJahr}" Width="Auto"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Text="LoSt-Art"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Path=BesondLoSt, Converter={StaticResource BesondereLohnsteuerConverter}}"/>
                </Grid>

            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate/>
</ListBox>
```

I even tried to call the VisualState in Code-Behind when the selection is being changed:

```
    public Lohnrechner()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Window.Current.SizeChanged += Current_SizeChanged;
        lbuser.SelectionChanged += lbuser_SelectionChanged;
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, ApplicationView.Value.ToString(), true);
    }

    void lbuser_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(lbuser, "Selected", true);
    }

    void Current_SizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, ApplicationView.Value.ToString(), true);
    }
```

Still doesn't work...

To make it clear: The code above sets the Background of a ListViewItem by using the VisualStateManager. It works in Windows Phone, but not with Windows Store apps.